# How do I change an xterm window color on an already open window?

Tags: linux, terminal, xterm

I have two xterm windows, window titled "A" and window titled "B".  I'd like to be able to dynamically change the -bg color of "B" from the "A" terminal.

something like:

from xterm "A"...
set xterm"B" -bg red

lastly, I'd to do this with only builtin capabilities of xterm (no addon apps please)....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo -en "\e]11;red\a" > /dev/pts/X
```

you still need to look up the correct value of `pts/X` which you can find in `ps` or `who` output.

Comment: Just use tty:   echo -en "\e]11;red\a" > `tty`